# Importance of Shared Package in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I realize that GWt doesn't compile the classes not in the Client package. But what is the importance of the shared package? What are the classes that I need to put in this package?

Comment: GWT will compile whatever packages you tell it to (in your .gwt.xml file), including any shared packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What are the classes that I need to
>   put in this package?

Any logic or data types that are used by both the client and the server. This will save you from **duplicating** code across both sides, and potentially keep the logic and data types **consistent**.

Comment: Do not place anything within the shared package that you don't intend on being client-side friendly; i.e. translatable..